# I am trying to run the MaxView document management program

Tags: document-management

I have downloaded MaxView 0.7 from    http://sourceforge.net/projects/maxview/

When I try to open the file the message is:

'Dependency is not satisfiable:libpoppler-qt 4-3(>=0.10) Error'

My goal is to get a Brother-MFC-9420-CN printer/scanner/fax online.  I have Ubuntu 14.04 as the OS on a Lenovo Think Centre desktop.  The system recognizes the printer, at least.

I appreciate your feedback.

Comment: You need to install the dependency libpoppler-qt 4-3 >=0.10

Comment: Thank you.  How do I install this?

Answer (score 0):

You can install the dependencies in two ways:

> Find a repository that has it, and add that repository
>
> Download and install with

dpkg -i package name

I found the package here: http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-poppler-qt4

Comment: Thank you.  Since I have a 32-bit OS, then should I select the i386?   Re:   http://packages.ubuntu.com/precise/python-poppler-qt4

Comment: Yes. Always install packages according to your architecture

Comment: I have downloaded this, and, sorry to say, nothing seems to be working.  I have Ubuntu 14.04.   Is it possible that another OS distro would be more compatible with the MaxView program?  Or is there something else I´m missing?   Thank you.

Comment: How did you tried to install it?

Comment: I went to the downloads folder and double clicked on it. The message is ´dependency not satisfiable libpopppler-qt 4.4(>=0.18) Error.... Is there another way to do it?  The OS doesn´t seem too user-friendly.  Thank you.

Comment: You can download the zip, extract and follow the INSTALL file.

Comment: I went to packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/zip and downloaded the i386 version.  I still can not install MaxView.  This is why I'm thinking that another distro might be better than Ubuntu 14.04.  Dunno.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Ubuntu. You need to know how to install packages by source. In that case, after you download the zip, you must decompress it, and run make (or qmake). You need to read the file INSTALL provided by the zip

Comment: I is my understanding that MaxView is no longer supported.  It has changed to Paperman...   https://github.com/sglass68/paperman    However, I don't know which file to download.    My goal is to replicate PaperPort and run the Brother scanner/printer.  Keep in mind, I am a layman, not a programmer.  My OS is Ubuntu 14.04.   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone coming across this thread in a search, the program's author has given directions on how to install PaperMan from source, here:
https://github.com/sglass68/paperman/wiki/Paperman-cross-platform-paper-mangement-like-PaperPort,-was-maxview

Scroll down, all the way to the bottom, to see it.

After doing this, it's installed on LinuxMint Qiana, with no dependency problems.  You set this by appending the folder path to the command, paperman. Otherwise, the program will refuse to scan, until the destination directory has been set.

Edit: *don't follow the author's instructions exactly!* If the source doesn't have a good uninstall rule, you won't be able to remove the program cleanly, when you decide to.  Instead use checkinstall, or another method to accomplish the same end. Do some research before bypassing your distro's installer.

Comment: While the link may contain the answer to the question you should also include the details in your answer in case the link goes offline.

Comment: Good idea, thanks for catching that!  Here is the lower part of that page:

**Building**
The packages are out of date, but building on a Debian/Ubuntu from source should be easy:

Install pre-requisites: apt-get install autotools-dev libqt4-dev cmake libtiff4-dev qt4-dev-tools libsane-dev libpoppler-qt4-dev cdbs g++ libpodofo-dev git

Go to a fresh directory: cd /some/dir

Get the source: git clone git://github.com/sglass68/paperman

cd paperman

Build it: ./configure

make

Run it: ./paperman /path/to/paper

(not sure you need autotools-dev and cdbs)

Comment: This program may have been stable in the OS versions of the time when it was written,  but I'm getting occasional seg faults and crashes -- at times.  It's a pity it's not being maintained, because it has no GNU/Linux native-equivalent.   This comment is just a heads-up for others considering following the installation instructions.